# Does Async Actions in Asp.Net Web Api help the user in some way?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, threadpool

If I have a Web Api service (no GUI), and the Get request of the user demands me to get data, which is going to take 15 seconds to retrieve it,

and lets say this is my Action:

```
  [HttpGet]   
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetSomeAsync([FromUri]NiceRequestObject request)
  {
     var response = await _niceService.F1Async(request); //15 seconds duration.
     return Request.CreateResponse(response);
  }
```

then what is the **benefit for the user**? The fact I released the thread back to the
thread pool...How will the user "feel" it some way? The user needs to wait these 15 seconds no matter what.

Comment: `what is the benefit for the user` a huge one - if you block too many threads, your CPU utilisation will rise so high IIS will be forced to recycle your app pool to prevent your site from freezing for everyone

Comment: You should ask `what is the benefit to me`? You'd pay for far fewer and smaller servers to serve the same traffic. Your API's reliability would go up. You'd avoid some cascading failures and complete farm crashes

Comment: I worked on a high traffic API once where the lead dev didn't thing async matters. CPU would hit the 90%s and result in long waits and even cascading failures as one server would recycle redirecting traffic to the others, which would hit the recycle limit and so on, until the farm came down. *Blocking* starts with spinwaiting because a) locks are supposed to be short-lived and b) rescheduling a thread is expensive. This means that a blocking request to the DB or another service will use 100% CPU before putting the thread to sleep. That's a lot of wasted AWS dollars

Comment: If you only expect one request, you should probably ditch controllers and most middleware altogether and [work with endpoints directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-basics) and eg `MapGet` . You'll see that `MapGet` expects asynchronous methods though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

This isn't a UI experience optimisation. It can improve UI experience but this is really a side effect. This helps you optimise your thread utilisation. Meaning you can process more requests with less threads. Meaning you can have a cheaper server and/or can process more requests on existing infrastructure.

---

> How will the user "feel" it some way?

The user will feel it when 10,000 people all request your page at the same time and your server has a better chance of processing all of those request (including this imaginary "user") without running out of threads. Ultimately though, this is a **server optimisation**.

> The user needs to wait these 15 seconds no matter what.

Unless all the threads on your server are used up, then the user will get an error when they request this resource (depending on other technology) and will have to resubmit. Meaning they will have to wait longer than 15 seconds.

Comment: To add to that, in a farm excessive blocking will cause traffic to switch to other servers, blocking them as well and result in a cascading failure that will bring down the farm.

Comment: To add some backswing to that, I work on Azure functions/AWS Lambda a lot. For these you pay for the computing **time**. Even if you async your function, you continue to pay while it waits. So In that particular scenario the benefit is limited and the context switching possibly slightly harms performance. But that's an edge case for most people. Functions/lambda don't have thread pools though, so off topic for this question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and Liam, Thank you both for your good comments and answer. If I understood correct, Async Action will help the server to deal with many requests together (because the server will have enough threads in the threadpool for them due to the async way), BUT lets say we live in a world with 1 user (which sends 1 request) Then....the user will just wait for the server to retrieve the data....and? meanwhile he/she will see just nothing for 15 seconds?

Comment: @SItzik what's your *actual* question? There's no such world. Even in IoT machines that are meant to handle only a few requests at a time blocking is bad - you could even say *worse*. Even if there was, you'd end up paying for a bigger machine to handle the same load.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would like you to focus please in an imaginary world with a Single request. It will help me to understand it better. Will it be correct that in such a world, Async actions will not be useful?

Comment: @SItzik I would like you to focus in a specific question. This is arguing for the sake of arguing and *yes* it would be useful, for a lot of reasons. Because *yes* it would block a thread, wouldn't consume extra power, would require *emulation from the OS's part* - Windows IO is asynchronous. Blocking is emulated. And many libraries are async only, eg HttpClient never had blocking operations. Other libraries chose not to produce blocking wrappers on top of their natively asynchronous operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then this is my specific question: In a world of 1 request (no requests before or after it), why should we use Async Actions?

Comment: @SItzik that's not a specific question, that's repeating the same vague question. Do you have a *specific problem you want to solve*?  A *specific environment*? Or trying to get people to agree with an opinion? SO is a Q&A site about specific programming problems. There are other StackExchange sites for discussions eg `softwareengineering` but even there people will require clarification

Comment: *I would like you to focus please in an imaginary world with a Single request* that is an **imaginary world** and focusing on that isn't helpful to you because it does not exist.

Comment: @SItzik if I had an app that expects a single request I would remove all middleware and use [endpoint routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-basics). The request handlers are all asynchronous though, by design. Web apps and APIs are inherently asynchronous and ASP.NET Core was built with that in mind